# pubsub not working

Tags: pubsublwc

I've gotten this to work before, but for some reason after fireEvent the listener is never reached.

js where fireEvent happens:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { fireEvent } from 'c/pubSub';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class MissionEdit extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    onSaveSuccess(event) {
        console.log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++onSaveSuccess'); //it makes it here
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, "changedMission");
        const toast = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Mission Updated!',
            message: 'Mission successfully modified',
            variant: 'success',
            mode: 'dismissable'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toast);
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, "changedMission");
    }
}
```

js listener:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import Utility from 'c/utility';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { registerListener, unregisterAllListeners } from 'c/pubSub';

export default class MissionDetailHeaderInfo extends Utility {

    @api recordId;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('RrosMissionDetailsPage----connectedCallback');
        registerListener("changedMission", this.handleChanged, this);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        console.log('disconnectedCallback');
        unregisterAllListeners(this);
    }

    handleChanged(event) {
        console.log('header refreshed +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');//doesn't reach here
        this.renderMissionHeaderDetails();
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you are able, it might be best to abandon the pub/sub "workaround" that you have adopted, and switch to [LMS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation)?

Comment: thanks @PhilW - Post the answer and I'll mark as the answer. This trailhead is a good example. First two units are for parent-child communication. The third unit covers this scenario. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pubsub](https://github.com/developerforce/pubsub) module is an open source "workaround" for use when you need to do cross-DOM communication (not parent/child or child/parent) but there is no official mechanism available in your usage context. It is less than ideal, and has various drawbacks and missing capabilities, such as:

- The need to explicitly track registrations so you can cleanly unregister when no longer subscribing - e.g. on component destruction.
- Problems with page references in different technology stacks (e.g. Aura/LWC vs Visualforce), though this has been alleviated with the introduction of [DomainCreator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm).
- Lack of support for cross-namespace messaging.

If you are able, it would be a good idea to adopt [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) (assuming you are working in usage contexts it supports) since this is an official, supported mechanism.

As mentioned in comments, trailhead covers [communicating between unrelated components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-between-unrelated-components) which might be a good place to start.